# How to install python-numpy on OSX using apt-get?

Tags: python, macos, numpy

so I have tried installing `numpy` using `Homebrew`. While it said on home-brew that I successfully installed it, the program I run couldn't detect it and it recommend using `apt-get`.
So I got `apt-get` through fink, but I couldn't install `numpy` like I wanted to.
The most relevant answer I found online is here:
http://mrprajesh.blogspot.hk/2009/11/e-couldnt-find-package-on-apt-get.html
But it only covers linux and I am not sure how to do the same on an OSX machine. Does anyone has experience with this?

Below is the error message. Any help is appreciated.

```
yings-mbp:madanalysis5 yvonne$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy

Reading Package Lists... Done

Building Dependency Tree... Done

E: Couldn't find package python-numpy

yings-mbp:madanalysis5 yvonne$ sudo apt-get install update

Password:

Reading Package Lists... Done

Building Dependency Tree... Done

E: Couldn't find package update

yings-mbp:madanalysis5 Sam$
```

Comment: Have you tried installing with pip?

Comment: I would never use `apt-get` on `OSX`. `homebrew` is a perfectly fine package manager. I would focus on solving the issues with `homebrew` instead of switching to `apt-get`. A very nice alternative, especially for beginners, is `anaconda`, which provides prebuilt binaries for complex packages like `numpy` and `scipy`.

Comment: Pip would be an easier method in my opinion..

Comment: Install pip with homebrew if you don't already have it..

Comment: Use `pip install numpy` or `sudo easy_install numpy` . apt-get is linux based won't work in mac. The alternative is `brew install python`. Another way is download the source and compile on your machine. This is the best.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to installing numpy and scipy, is just download Anaconda, even though its large, things are compiled and just work.  If you need a smaller package then get miniconda, and run "conda install numpy".  If you don't care for space, just get anaconda.